# GUI for Azure DevOps no longer available

Tags: msbuild

When I add a new Build Definition in Azure Pipelines the GUI is no longer available. The YAML tool appears.

My team needs to gradually move over to YAML. I know the GUI works for existing pipelines but we would like to create new pipelines with the GUI too.

N/A

Answer (score 0):

Click on the `Use the classic editor` link when creating a new pipeline:

[image]